# .htaccess RewriteRule - different behavior on localhost and 1and1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file has this line:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

When I go to `http://localhost/blah/profile/name` (I'm using XAMPP), in profile.php I can say:

```
$user_name = $_GET['username']
```

This works fine. But when I deploy it to my 1and1 server and go to `http://blah.com/profile/name`, `$_GET['username']` is not set. Why is it behaving differently?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your 1and1 webserver?

Comment: I don't see mod_rewrite in phpinfo(). Is it supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off `Multiviews`:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

With multiviews turned on, mod_negotiation will attempt to match (along with its PATH INFO) the request to existing files. So that module will see `/profile/something` and then see that there's a `/profile.php`, and simply send the request right to `/profile.php`, completely bypassing mod_rewrite and your rules.

Comment: @WhiteAlligator make sure mod_rewrite is turned on (which may involve contacting 1&1 support)

Comment: @WhiteAlligator Which is what I suggested above. Sometimes hosting companies turn it off or don't enable it by default. If you compiled your webserver yourself, you may need to re-compile with that package.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the quick fix - just pulling parameters from the url myself.

Comment: I have the issue with the zend framework site on 1&1 hosting. At admin for pagination purposes, i used url paramters like ?p=1&ipp=10, and it is not working only on 1&1. I tried to put options -Multiviews in htaccess, but did not work for me. Can you please help me in this regard?